# Can't complete tinymce profile to Login

Tags: tinymce

I am new to tinymce. After I register using a google account, I am asked to add my name, role, detail of project, when I expect to complete the project which I do. Problem is that the 'Start using Tiny' button does not become active and I can't click it. Then I get redirected to a blank page (URL is https://www.tiny.cloud/my-account/error/service-connectivity-error). What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Entered profile details after registering, expected to be able to continue to getting an api key but not able to.